# How to show ... at the end of string if it doesn't fit 1 line in TextView?

Tags: android

I use android:maxLines="1" right now but I'd rather have "..." at the end of this line. Preferably fading off. Is it possible with TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only possible, but built into the framework.

The XML flag for the TextView is [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize), and the related TextView method is [setEllipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29).